# Is there any merit to think about perfect numbers as the volumes of n-dimensional rectangular prisms?

Tags: geometry, number-theory, prime-numbers

I was messing around with perfect numbers, and I had the random thought of representing the perfect numbers as a subset of the set of volumes of a special class of $n$-dimensional rectangular prisms.

The dimension, $n$, will be decided by the number of factors that the perfect number being talked about has, excluding the perfect number itself, and including $1$.

The primary defining feature of this set of rectangular prisms would be that the the "perimeter"(sum of all the edges) would be equal to $2n$ times the "volume"(product of all edges) of the prism. We could then try to find some further restrictions on the prisms.

Is there any merit to this geometric representation? I don't really think so, but it is worth a shot for me.

Comment: How would you define the "perimeter of a prism"? Surface area? Sum of edge lengths?

Comment: Well as I said in the post, it's the sum of all sides, aka edges.

Comment: Well, "side" is ambiguous, hence why I asked. Also, in what dimension are we working in, relative to the perfect number? For instance, consider $6$. I assume the dimensions are coming from the factors, so do we work in $3$ dimensions by neglecting $6$ as a factor (so the proper factors sum to $6$), or do we work in $4$ dimensions by including $6$ (so the factors all sum to $2 \cdot 6 = 12$)? I don't know if there's really merit in this framing of it, honestly, maybe there is -- but I think it's something that needs to be played with more and have its kinks/setup/ambiguities ironed out first.

Comment: So yes, as the first situation suggests, the dimension will be based on the number of factors not including the perfect number itself. So for 6, the dimension is 3, for 28 the dimension is 5, and so forth. I think I'll need to clear up the ambiguities in the question a bit more.